# No Changed Rows Produced by this mySQL update query. Why?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am at a loss this morning.  Maybe my coffee was drugged?  Simple problem- get the existing ids into this temp table for an export.

Tables like so:

Table person

```
+--------+-----------------------+
| id     | email                 |
+--------+-----------------------+
| 142755 | xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com |
+--------+-----------------------+
```

Table no_dma

```
+--------+------------------------+
| person | email                  |
+--------+------------------------+
|     0  | xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com  |
+--------+------------------------+
```

Query:

```
UPDATE 
person, no_dma
SET no_dma.person = person.id
WHERE person.email = no_dma.email;
```

I have verified the existence of at least some matching email addresses in the two tables but the update produces

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (9.31 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Clearly I have a little dain bramamge today.

Help me out?  What am I doing incorrectly?

// EDIT

Per comments below I made these queries:

```
mysql> select person, email from no_dma limit 0,1;
+--------+------------------------+
| person | email                  |
+--------+------------------------+
 |     0 | tom_r1989@xxxxxxx.com
+--------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select email from no_dma where email = 'tom_r1989@xxxxxxx.com';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select email from no_dma where TRIM(email) = 'tom_r1989@xxxxxxx.com';
Empty set (0.46 sec)
```

Both tables have email field stored as varchar with collation set to latin1_swedish_ci.

And this this query, WTH?

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('"',email,'"') from no_dma limit 0,3;
+-----------------------+
| CONCAT('"',email,'"') |
+-----------------------+
"  |amjor308@xxx.com
"   |utt@xxx.com
"  |00000000@xxx.com
+-----------------------+


mysql> SELECT email from no_dma limit 0,3;
+--------------------+
| email              |
+--------------------+
 |+amjor308@xxx.com
  |mutt@xxx.com
 |000000000@xxx.com
+--------------------+
```

What is going on there?  Looks like newlines but I thought TRIM() handled those?

```
mysql> SELECT TRIM(email) from no_dma limit 0,3;
+--------------------+
| TRIM(email)        |
+--------------------+
 |+amjor308@aol.com
  |mutt@excite.com
 |000000000@aol.com
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE:  FOUND ISSUE
import was done on a Windows generated CSV but mysqlimport was given arg**

--lines-terminated-by='\n'

**Reimported data works fine.
Sorry to have wasted folks time.**

Comment: How did you verify? Do you get rows when you run `SELECT person.id FROM person, no_dma WHERE person.email = no_dma.email`?

Comment: I think I see an extra space in your example for no_dma.email at the end, try a `SELECT CONCAT('"',email,'"') from no_dma` to see if that's the case.

Comment: Unrelated, but you might want to lookup INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... if you want to export all data to another table in one go and update already existing rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table no_dma has a trailing space. The data is not the same.

Edit:

- SET ANSI_PADDING?
- Is it really a space: `&nbsp;` is ASCII 160
- What does a hash or checksum of each value reveal?
- What are the string lengths?

Comment: trailing space? I'm kinda confused ... usually I would think you are crazy but given your badges I beg to differ ... I don't get it

Comment: @Raffael1984: it's the difference between "my@email.com" and "my@email.com ".

Comment: not really ... the sql-statement-parser usually ignores spaces. and your example would apply only for comparing strings

Answer (score 1):

The statement is fine, I think. B/c I tested it and it worked.